# I am getting error in FitNesse while slim communication with browser _ Could not send/receive data with SUT

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

The error I got is
**fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimCommunicationException: Could not send/receive data with SUT**

**FitNesse Code:**

!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\FitNesseUsingSelenium\bin\Debug*.dll

!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner %p}

!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\FitSharp.2.5.0\lib\net40\Runner.exe}

!|import|
|FitNesseUsingSelenium|

!|FitSeleniumFramework|

|TextInTitle|isTitleCorrect?|

|Google|yes|

|google|no|

|bing|no|

Actually is it opening and closing the browser perfectly but after the instead of displaying the results in FitNesse page, it always throwing the error ***"Could not complete testing: fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimCommunicationException: Could not send/receive data with SUT"***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSBOF.png)

**But the same is working perfectly in Java using selenium**

Could you please suggest some idea to resolve this issue???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line:

```
!define slim.port {8085}
```

There seems to a problem in the latest FitNesse version when using Selenium and fitSharp with the default Slim port.  This is a workaround for the problem.